# How to write a file path that will point to a directory?

Tags: javascript, path, relative-path, framerjs

How to write a file path that will point to a directory.

From what I have googled, 
/path means root, 
./path means current directory, 
../path means parent directory

I am playing with Framer.js + Yeoman.

If you look at the screenshot attached:
[image]

`myLayers = Framer.Importer.load("../imported/test1")` is not working?
When I put the "imported" folder under the "app" folder it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to hope out one more parent directory, to the root test1.framer directory, before you can go into the imported directory. ie:

```
myLayers= Framer.Importer.load("../../imported/test1")
```

(starting from main.js file and only going up one parent directory only gets you in the app directory)

Comment: Tried that and it is still not working. Error is: http://localhost:9000/imported/test1/layers.json 404 (Not Found)